# Compare two lists of custom objects by a specified method C#

Tags: c#, linq

I know questions with same title have been asked before, but this is my case:

I want to compare two lists of custom objects which do not override `Equals` nor they implement `IEqualityComparer` but I want to compare them against a static comparison method like:

```
public class Custom
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public static bool Compare(Custom A, Custom B)
{
    return A.Prop1 == B.Prop1 && A.Prop2 == B.Prop2;
}
```

Assuming that the lists have the elements in same order:

```
List<Custom> l1 = new List<Custom> {new Custom { Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "B"}, new Custom { Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "B" } };
List<Custom> l2 = new List<Custom> { new Custom { Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "B" }, new Custom { Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "b" } };
```

I am trying to avoid a for like this:

```
if(l1.Count != l2.Count)return;
for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
{
    if(!Compare(l1[i], l2[i]))return;
}
bool comparisonResult = true;
```

using linq, but I guess I am missing something:

```
bool comparisonResult = l1.Any(x => l2.Any(y => Compare(x, y)));
```

This is what have tried, but it keeps returning `true` when lists are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use LINQ and don't want to implement an `IEqualityComparer` for `Custom`...

Assuming the two lists are in the proper sequence, you can make use of [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) to create a new list with each item side-by-side, kind of like a `Tuple`. You can then call All on that new list to call your static `Compare` method:

```
  List<Custom> l1 = new List<Custom> {new Custom { Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "B"}, new Custom { Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "B" } };
  List<Custom> l2 = new List<Custom> { new Custom { Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "B" }, new Custom { Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "b" } };

  bool comparisonResult = l1.Zip(l2, (x, y) => new { x, y }).All(z => Compare(z.x, z.y));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `All`

```
bool comparisonResult = l1.All(x => l2.Any(y => Compare(x, y)));
```

This will return true only if all the items in l1 match the inner condition - which is that they exist in the l2. This is an easier to read way that applying "not" twice.

This will not solve the case of duplicated items in lists so you can:

1. Distinct the lists
2. Do in the inner function a Where and count equals to 1

Comment: I have just tested your answer, as it seems interesting for me, but it didn't worked, still returned true, for different lists. But I can't explain why, the logic seems good in this case